# MultiColumn ComboBox

Tags: combobox, extjs3

I create a form with a combox that contains 2 fields: label and name
this is my combobox:

```
xtype           : 'combo',
id              : 'Sexe',
fieldLabel      : 'Sexe',
name            : "Sexe",
triggerAction   : "all",
store: 
    new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields  : ['label', 'name'],
        data    : [ ['m', 'Male'],['f', 'female']]
    }),
mode            :'local',
displayField    : "name",
valueField      : 'label',
forceSelection  : true,
editable        : false
```

When I send the form informations to PHP, the variable Sexe contains Male or female and not m or f. Or i want to contain the 'label' not the 'name'.
I put `valueField : 'label'`  but always send the 'name' not the 'label'.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: how are you sending the form data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ExtJS3 or ExtJS4? Because in ExtJS3, the combobox is submitted by the "hiddenName" and not by the "name". So in your example you should replace

```
name:"Sexe"
```

with

```
hiddenName:"Sexe"
```

An since you are using "mode" instead of "queryMode", i assume you are using ExtJS3.